# Infinitely small functions!

Tags: analysis

Suppose that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) =A$ and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) =B$ and $B \neq 0$. Then
$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{\lim_{x\to a} f(x)}{\lim_{x\to a} g(x)} = \frac{A}{B}$.

This is really well known and very easy to prove by the regular definition of limits, but I'm dealing with another proof which I think is way more direct!
But I'm not sure if a fact at the end of the proof is correct, in fact I don't have a clear idea how to show that fact instead of just saying the conclusion!

So here is my proof:

From the definition, if a function has a limit then that function can be shown as the sum of his limit and an infinitely small function:
So $f(x)=A+\alpha(x)$ where $\alpha(x)$ is infinitely small as $x \to a$.
On the other hand $g(x)=B+\beta(x)$ where $\beta(x)$ is also an infintely small function as $x \to a$.
Now,  $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{A+\alpha(x)}{B+\beta(x)}=\frac{A}{B} + \left [\frac{A+\alpha(x)}{B+\beta(x)}-\frac{A}{B} \right]$. 
So by the same definition used at the beginning we have the desired, where $\left [\frac{A+\alpha(x)}{B+\beta(x)}-\frac{A}{B} \right]$ infinitely small as $x \to a$.

So my question is how to show that the last part is infinitely small(as claimed before)?!

Comment: What you are doing is nothing other then the taylor series of order 0, with error terms $\alpha(x),\beta(x)$ (that are not infinitely small, how is that even defined?, but simply 0 at the point a and at most of linear order around that). However to prove such things you already need to know the convergence result you want to prove...

Comment: An infinitely small function is a function such that $\lim_{x \to a}{\alpha(x)}=0$. @mlk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that

$$\displaystyle \frac{A+\alpha(x)}{B+\beta(x)}-\frac{A}{B}=\frac{B\alpha(x)-A\beta(x)}{B^2+B\beta (x)}.$$

Since $\alpha(x),\beta(x)\to 0$ as $x\to a$ we have, by definition of limit:

$\forall \epsilon >0 \exists \delta_1>0 \quad\text{s.t.}\quad 0<|x-a|<\delta_1\implies |\alpha(x)|<\epsilon, $ and $\forall \epsilon >0 \exists \delta_2>0  \quad\text{s.t.}\quad 0<|x-a|<\delta_2\implies |\beta(x)|<\epsilon.$

Taking $\epsilon \le |B|/2$ and $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$ we have that

$$\displaystyle \left|\frac{B\alpha(x)-A\beta(x)}{B^2+B\beta (x)}\right|\le \frac{|B||\alpha(x)|+|A||\beta(x)|}{B^2-|B||\beta (x)|}\le \frac{(|A|+|B|)\epsilon}{B^2-\frac{B^2}{2}}=\frac{2(|A|+|B|)}{B^2}\epsilon .$$

I think that now you can conclude.

Comment: Thanks, but why we cannot conclude that $\lim_{x\to a}{\left [ \frac{A+\alpha(x)}{B+\beta(x)}-\frac{A}{B}\right ]}=0$  because $\lim_{x\to a}{\alpha(x)}=0$ and $\lim_{x\to a}{\beta(x)}=0$ ?! @mfl

Comment: Ok this is what you have concluded, so we cannot conclude direct using the rule that is to be proved at the beginning, without showing it with the definition! Ok thanks...

Comment: @mfl Hello , can I ask you something about proving this one?